# Was there ever such a thing as a Court Tory?

Tags: england

Were all Tories part of the Country 'party'? Were some of them part of the court party? What was the distinction between Country and non-Country Tories, if there were any?

Comment: What do you want to know that isn't covered by the [respective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whigs_(British_political_party)) [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tories_(British_political_party)) [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_Party_(Britain))?

Comment: Please reference all non-trivial concepts.

Comment: The very first sentence on the Country party's Wikipedia page (ht @SteveBird) seems to answer this, no? "In Britain in the era 1680–1740, especially in the days of Robert Walpole (1720s to 1740s), the Country Party was a coalition of Tories and disaffected Whigs."

Comment: This is an intriguing question about a interesting period of history.  As written it is broad and unclear, but I hope that with a little bit of editing it could be a good question.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace I think that's the sweetest thing you've ever said to me ;-). I've refined the question, I hope you'll all consider reopening it.